# Amperage on Main Neutral cause a High Electric Bill

Tags: electrical

My neighbours power bill was high from the electric company. They called an electrician and they noticed that the main panels, main neutral was carrying a couple of amps on it (verified with clamp on ammeter). Upon further inspection they noticed that the main ground wire was cut. After replacing the main ground with a new wire and ground plate apparently the power bill came down a bit.

Does that make sense? Or would it be random that the power bill came down? I understand now that the ground wire just provides a reference for voltage so to me this coincidence...

Either way there electric bill is still a few hundred dollars too high every two months. Are there any reasons you can think that a electric bill might be too high? Its a newer house with energy efficient everything. (Well insulated, heat pump etc). No large loads.

We are thinking it could be a hydro thing but I cannot think what on there end would cause it.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: A few hundred dollars too high every two months?!  I know of no good way to answer this without knowing great detail about the house. Heat pumps can perform very poorly due to incorrect installation.  For example, the system refrigerant charge might be very wrong, or a/c and resistive backup heat may run simultaneously due to incorrect control wiring, wasting huge amounts of energy.

Comment: The grounded (neutral) service conductor should carry the unbalanced load, so will likely be at least a few amperes flowing. The only way you should read 0 amperes, is if the load is completely balanced, or there's no load (in which case it's balanced at 0).

Comment: Yes I always understood the neutral carried the unbalanced load. I went to this call a few years ago when I was a third year apprentice and my journeyman told me the neural having amps on it was the reason of the high electric bill. And if we replaced the broken main ground that would fix it... Now they are my neighbour, and I am trying to help them. Chris is there any simple way to see if the heat pump is acting up or is this in a HVAC's spectrum... Just not sure where I should go from here. Any ideas?

Comment: (1) Confirm the system has resistive electric backup heat.  (2) Put an amp meter on the circuit feeding the backup and switch the system on in various modes to confirm the backup does not operate unexpectedly.  The backup heat should never activate during cooling, for instance.  Regarding refrigerant charge, etc, check the outdoor temperature split in a/c mode when the outdoor ambient is at least 80F.  On modern units, air leaving the condenser should be roughly 15F-20F warmer than air entering.  Much different than that indicates a problem.